# How do i identify a character in a text file and turn it into an object in a map?

Tags: java

I am programming a game and the level maps are text files. How do i take those text files and turn them into the map in java?

Example:

> ```
> > ##########
> > #b  X   X#
> > #        #
> > #   C    #
> > #        #
> > #      # #
> > #  C   #C#
> > #     O# #
> > #  X   #E#
> > ##########
> ```

E is a moving object

#
 are walls

c 
are boxes

x 
are targets

b 
is the battery of the moving object

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you firstly load the file using a BufferedReader, which provides a `readLine` method, and then transform the String it returns into a `char` array (using `toCharArray()` method).

You can, after that, parse every character by using a `switch` structure, in a `foreach` loop. It would give something like this :

```
for(char charac : data.toCharArray()) {
switch(charac) {
     case '#' :
          solidTiles.add(new Wall(posX, posY)); //where solidTiles is an 
                                                //ArrayList of tiles
          break;
     case ' ' :
          //is a blank space, so do nothing (or add a new tile to some list, etc.)
           break;
     case 'E' : 
          entities.add(new MovingEntity(posX, posY)); //etc.
          break;
}
}
```

Hope it helped you :)